# Display results in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Is there any way to display htaccess directives results in real time? For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}
```

Are there any instructions that can be placed inside htaccess to display `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` value?

I know that can be accomplished with a PHP script in the right address, but I was wondering if it's also possible inside htaccess?

Comment: That's a good question. Unfortunately I don't think it is possible in real time. I guess you have to check the log to review the results.

Comment: In the target address without the need to have a PHP script in the page.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?docroot=%{DOCUMENT_ROOT} [L,QSA]
```

Didn't have the possibility to test this but should work

From the [Apache 2.2 documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

> In addition to plain text, the Substition string can include
>
> - back-references ($N) to the RewriteRule pattern
> - back-references (%N) to the last matched RewriteCond pattern
> - server-variables as in rule condition test-strings (%{VARNAME})
> - mapping-function calls (${mapname:key|default})

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It redirects to the superior directory, which is not the idea but it can be corrected. It doesn't display any information, though.

Comment: It doesn't redirect anywhere but rewrites the URL to itself with appended document root. If you would be more specific on what you actually want maybe we could help you better. If this is for some kind of debugging you could change [L,QSR] to [L,QSR,R=301] which will do a redirect and display the doc root in your browsers address bar

Comment: Yes, the information is to be used exclusively in a test enviroment. As to the question, I wanted to find out if there are any instructions or directives that can be placed inside htaccess to echo it's results in real time. At this moment I am pretty sure there aren't, so I really appreciate your help but don't want to waste your time. I am upvoting your answer, now that I can. Thank you.